# Stop Dynamic Table Reloading IndexPath - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic tableView as below, which shows names of an array according to `indexpath.row`. And in each cell I have a button that changes the name which is as a deletage to the cell as in the code below. When I load the table assume the rows load as below:

Name1

Name2

Name3

Name4

Name5

Name6

Name7

Name8

And then I click the button and change Name4 to NewName for example. It is changed when the button is clicked but when you scroll in the table, when it comes to the `indexpath.row` of Name4 again (where `indexpath.row==3` in this case), NewName changes back to Name4. How can I stop the the table to load everytime when the `indexpath.row` is changing? Or how can I find another solution to this problem?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:NamesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! NamesCell

    cell.NameCell1003 = self
    cell.nameLbl.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func NameCell1003(cell: NamesCell)
{
    cell.nameLbl.text= "NewName"
}
```

Comment: A cell's text is based on the data in your `resultsNameArray`. You need to update that array when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rmaddy is correct that you want to change the underlying data in the array and reload the TableView to achieve the behavior you want.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:NamesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! NamesCell

    cell.nameLbl.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func NameCell1003(cell: NamesCell)
{
    self.resultsNameArray[indexYouWantToChange] = "NewName"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You will need a reference to the UITableView, usually this is an IBOutlet, to call reloadData on it. In the code I just called it "tableView". If your resultsNameArray is very large, think more than several hundred items, you might investigate using:

```
func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath],
           withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

That will let you update just the rows you need. For a small number of rows like what you state in your question, reloadData is fine and simpler to implement.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!